# Is there a "correct" way to store an application's login session?

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication

I'm working on a small app that has two activities: a splash screen with login and register forms, and an interface for the application's main purpose. The users must log into the splash activity to access the interface activity.

I've implemented the splash activity's login and register, and I'm now wondering how to store the session data for the application's persistent access.

I've considered a few options:

- Extending the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and creating member variables to hold the data. I see a few problems with this approach. For one, the API mentions that extending the Application class is usually unnecessary, leading me to believe that employing it for data storage would not be the best approach. More importantly, this data would only last as long as the application itself on the memory; the login data is lost if the user exits the application.
- Using application's [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref), a convenient data storage abstraction api of the operating system. The only problem with this method is that only primitive data types can be stored, and my session key is a String of a hash.
- Using internal storage. This involves writing files and lots of IO, which sounds too complicated for the few strings I want to store.

Are there any options I haven't considered? Of these options which one would be more practical to use?

Comment: You can store strings in shared preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your can use static variables and set it when user is authenticate, after that authenticate used that variable for rest of things